# Fail to populate html table with java hashmap using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dictionary, hashmap

I have an employeeDB class where I set the connection to the db and I can retrieve data from my db. In this class I have a func that called `getAllEmployee` where I use to retrieve the data, it looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeDB {

    private Connection connection;

    public EmployeeDB() {
        connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
    }

    public HashMap<String, List<String>> getAllEmployee() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        HashMap<String, List<String>> total = new HashMap<>();

        try {

            Statement statementE = connection.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement pStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select month from paycheck where id=?");

            ResultSet rse = statementE.executeQuery("select id from employee");


            while (rse.next()) {    
                List<String> months = new ArrayList<>();

                pStatement.setString(1, rse.getString("id"));
                ResultSet rs = pStatement.executeQuery();


                while (rs.next()) {
                    months.add(rs.getString("month"));
                }

                total.put(rse.getString("id"), months);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

now, im calling this method from my servlet "EmployeeInfo" and returning it the hashmap that have all the pairs of data that I need (i already printed it and saw I have the correct data).

Now I want from the servlet to set this hashmap as an attribute of the session, then go to my jsp file and populate a table with this hashmap data. this is my servlet:

```
public class EmployeeInfo extends HttpServlet {

    private final EmployeeDB edb;

    public EmployeeInfo() {
        super();
        edb = new EmployeeDB();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
        Employee e = new Employee();
        Employee retEmp = new Employee();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> total = new HashMap<>();
        e.setId(request.getParameter("ID"));

        try {
            retEmp = edb.getEmpInfo(e.getId());

            if (e.getId().equals("")) {
                total=edb.getAllEmployee();
                request.getSession().setAttribute("EmployeeHashMap", total);
                forward = "AllEmployee.jsp?";
            }            
            else if (retEmp.getId() == null) {
                forward = "errorID.jsp?";
            } else {

                request.getSession().setAttribute("newEmployee", retEmp);
                forward = "WelcomeUser.jsp";
            }
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
            view.forward(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

now in my `AllEmployee.jsp` I want to populate the table and it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="ptable" border="1">

            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">Month</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${EmployeeHashMap}" >
                <!-- entry.key is employee.key -->
                <!-- entry.value is employee.skills -->
                <c:forEach var="skillId" items="${entry.value}" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>${entry.key}</td>
                        <td>${skillId}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>Type a message
```

I have no idea why its not working and i can see an empty table...
please try to help me figure this out. thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try to debug this and find out what is returned by `edb.getAllEmployee();`? Shouldn't `EmployeeHashMap` be a request attribute?

Comment: yes its returning a hashmap and i printed it too to the consol, and yes it is setted to be an attribute `equest.getSession().setAttribute("EmployeeHashMap", total)` @RC.

Comment: You have not declared a TAGLIB directive for the JSTL library in your JSP: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm. Add this to the top of your JSP: <%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: You can confirm this by rightclick, *"View page source"* in webbrowser. Obviously, you should not see any unparsed JSP/JSTL tags at all, but only the generated HTML output.

Comment: @AlanHay thanks brooo you are the man :) please add it as an answer